# changing style with jquery with :after

Tags: jquery, css

I made a short example of the problem I'm dealing with.

Html code:

```
<ul class="BB"> 
  <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
.BB a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

.BB > li:after {
    border-right: 2px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

**Question:**
How to change the border-right and border_bottom color to #000 when mouse is on a:hover but only the element `<li>` which contains `<a>` that I'm pointing with the mouse?

I tried jquery like this

```
$('.BB a').hover(function(){
  $('ul.BB > li').toggleClass('hov'); 
}
```

and the CSS

```
.BB > li.hov:after {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

but this way I change all the `<li>`

Comment: You should be doing this with CSS only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the pseudo element doesn't have a `content` property. If it doesn't have a `content` property/value, the pseudo element won't show up.

```
.BB > li:after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 2px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}
```

If you want to change the class of the `li` element when hovering over the child `a` element, you need to use `$(this)` within the event handler. Then you would transverse the DOM using the `.parent()` method - `$(this).parent('li')`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fqjL6tsL/)

```
$('.BB a').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('hov'); 
});
```

---

### Without jQuery:

You may not actually need jQuery to do any of this though. You could just use the CSS `:hover` pseudo class:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/n1wpn77t/)

```
.BB > li:after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 2px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}
.BB > li:hover:after {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

The only difference with this is that the color of the border is changing when hovering over the `li` elements rather than the `a` elements as it does in the jQuery example. If this is a problem, you could also add the psuedo element to the `a` elements rather than the `li` elements:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqx0yc2L/)

```
.BB > li a:after {
    content: '';
    border-right: 2px solid #DDD;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
}
.BB > li:hover a:after {
    border-right: 2px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: you're right. I just wrote the idea of my problem. Thank you.

Comment: It works better with jQuery in my case because it changes all at the same time (color of a element and border color). If I do only CSS and slowly hover the elements it changes first li then a.